# Linux not recognizing seagate usb drive

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I have a new 4TB Seagate Expansion drive. I have tried this in both the USB3.0 and USB2.0 ports and get similar results.

dmesg shows the drive getting noticed:

```
[  235.370616] usb 9-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  235.396485] usb 9-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3322
[  235.396490] usb 9-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  235.396493] usb 9-2: Product: Expansion Desk
[  235.396496] usb 9-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  235.396498] usb 9-2: SerialNumber: NA8X48HB
```

It shows up in lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:9311 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 003: ID 0bc2:3322 Seagate RSS LLC
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 1058:25e2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But there is no device file connected with it. fdisk -l doesn't list it, gparted doesn't see it, nothing. So the system sees it, but doesn't give it a device file or any way to access it.

I've done all kinds of swapping out of different hardware, and I'm convinced everything is working fine. I have another seagate drive that isn't recognized either. The WD drives seem to be happy, it just won't see my seagate drives. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to recognize it as an USB peripheral but not as a mass storage. You are not saying with which linux kernel version/linux distribution, nor if you tried on any other host. Nor with specific model of drive. This may help others give you relevant answers.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. The uas module wasn't loading. modprobe uas cleared it up.

Comment: @mps_ftw: What’s the name of the module? Could you please write an answer about your solution even if it’s short?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and rebooting fixed it. It may be related to the fact that I upgraded my kernel version but hadn't restarted yet (so hadn't switched to the new one).